# maven pom.xml perform task during goal

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml

We have a primary project that is java, as a part of it we need to pull into the final package some custom js files that are contained within a separate git repo (and tagged with versions). What would the best way be to download and place these files in the correct location during the build process? Should I just use antrun scripts?

Comment: The best way is to deploy those dependencies into a repository and use them in your primary project as a dependency. that's the Maven way.

Answer (score 0):

It deppends how your files are organized, but it seems, that git submodules could be good idea. 
Posisible issues

- I do not know how it work with tags, it seems it works only with branches.
- You can only pull whole submodule repository to empty dir.

Comment: Do you know any way to submodule a specific commit?

Comment: Did not understand question? Do you want always checkout same submodule question? I do not think there is a way. I think at most you checkput specific branch, and I am not sure about that